# git subtree pull command doesn't update subtree project

Tags: git

**Problem**
I'm trying to update my subtree project, but Git doesn't update my subtree, instead it throws:

```
Already up-to-date.
```

**What I want to achieve:**

I have a Rails app (my API) and a Javascript app (my frontend). I need both projects in one directory, so I added the frontend as submodule to the Rails app.

```
/main-project
    /... rails dirs
    /public/frontend
```

Thats how I added the subtree:

```
git subtree add --prefix=public/frontend --squash MY_REMOTE_GIT_REPO master
```

And I ignored the files in `public/frontend` with `.gitignore` (because I don't want to push the whole project if there are only frontend changes).

Now when I'm updating the frontend, pushing the changes to my remote repo and trying to update the frontend in my Rails app with `git subtree pull --prefix=public/frontend` it throws `Already up-to-date.`, even if there are new commits in my remote repo.

It's important for me, that I don't have to deploy the whole app (API and frontend) if there a only changes on the API **or** the frontend.